# Are there any tools to migrate code to be rails4 ready

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Are there any tools to migrate our existing app from 3.2.x to be rails4 ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aware of tools, but here is a guide you can follow to do that

1. [Upgrading to Rails 4 Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0)
2. [Get Your App Ready for Rails 4](http://rubysource.com/get-your-app-ready-for-rails-4/)